# RAID 1 Intel Storage rapid

Tags: администрирование, резервное-копирование, raid

Делал бэкап сервера.
Прошлые диски были по 1 тб.
Нашел у себя по 4 тб только.
На один из них через акронис сделал бэкап, проверил и поставил второй,пустой диск.

через Intel Storage Repit  хотел сделать RAID 1, но пишет удалю все на этих дисках,а потом сделаю.
Есть выбор, на каком диске делать хранить данные, не активна.
Что не так делаю?
Нужно было сразу разливать на зеркало?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, нужно было сразу делать зеркало.

Диск из зеркала содержит метаданные, причем расположенные там, где у "обычного" диска расположены "просто данные", так что конвертация обычного диска в зеркало - нетривиальная процедура.

Comment: А если отпадет один диск в массиве, как подсовывать?

Comment: Так зеркало при этом уже создано. А утилита управления массивом умеет добавлять диски